# Receipt doesn't refresh on auto-renewing subscription?

Tags: swift, macos, storekit

I have an auto-renewing subscription in my macOS app. The initial purchase refreshes the app receipt, which can be locally checked to validate whether the user has an active subscription.

When the subscription automatically renews, the app receipt is not updated. Even when the transaction passes through the `SKPaymentQueue` on app relaunch, the receipt is still not updated.

The only way I've managed to get a current receipt is to use `SKReceiptRefreshRequest`, but this prompts the user to input their App Store login credentials.

How can I make sure the user's subscription information in the receipt is up to date without using server-side receipt validation?

EDIT: The behavior described reflects my experience with the StoreKit sandbox. If the same behavior can be confirmed to be nonexistent in production, that would be awesome.

Comment: I don't honestly know. But maybe that how things work? As long as the subscription either *exists* or *is current*, the receipt is there? And then, by definition, it's up to *the user* to... (1) opt out, (2) not renew because of that, and (3) re-subscribe if they desire? If that is Apple's way then all you care about is *does* a subscription receipt exist. And - maybe - this initial purchase should check for (simply) a subscription - without caring if it's active or not - before charging anything? Another alternative is to check `SKReiptRefeshResquest` both timely (by code) and with respect?

Comment: looks like a bug in your code. Check get receipt function. Receipt updates when new transaction or renew was success. For me it works fine. Print received receipt to log.

Comment: @AleyRobotics What receipt function are you referring to specifically?

Comment: Actually the receipt will be automatically updated, when you make the Product Request `SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as Set<String>)'. You need to perform this action as soon as the user enters the app or when he's accessing the paid functionality. Maybe I can help you out, if you post your relevant IAP code.

Comment: @AlexWoe89 Interesting! I already have a function implemented to make a product request easily. I'll give this a try!

Comment: @AlexWoe89 So I requested the subscription product using SKProductsRequest as you described. Afterward, the receipt still showed no renewal.

Comment: In which part of your receipt dict are you looking? in may case I had to look into  the dict values of key = "latest_receipt_info"

Comment: @AlexWoe89 The "latest_receipt_info" key is a part of the receipt you get when you verify receipts over the web with Apple. It doesn't exist (from what I can tell) in the local receipt, which is stored on the user's device in the app bundle. Since I'm verifying locally, I only have the local receipt to work with.